# Kodi not loading on 20.04LTS

Tags: apt, 20.04, software-installation, ppa

Have tried repeatedly to get Kodi to load on my Intel NUC N2830.
I have the weird situation that it oscillates between Kodi and Ubuntu showing only a 1/4 of each in the top left hand of the screen.
Restarting gets me back to the Ubuntu screen and everything works.
However if I try to start Kodi it oscillates again.
Have completely purged Kodi from the system using sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove kodi   Still the same result.
I did download using the ppa ppa:team-xbmc/ppa which gave me Martix 19.1
When this did not work ,after a complete purge ,I used the software downloader which installed 18.6 but same result.
Is my only option to reinstall Ubuntu and start again?
Geoff

Comment: Could you post a screenshot or a photo of what you mean when you say "it oscillates between Kodi and Ubuntu showing only 1/4 of each in the top left hand of the screen"? This may make it easier for someone to recognise the issue and offer a solution 

Comment: Have found the problem I think.